.htaccess - Trying to remove /profile/ from urls
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ https://example.com/?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^profile/(followers|friends|saved|stories)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC] 

I have also tried this rule too
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) /?username=$2 [L,QSA,NC] 

But, when I visit the /user/ or /profile/user/ links after making these changes, they forward to a 404 Page Not Found.

What are the intended targets for such requests. Please give examples in natural language of the intended from/to mappings. In the first rule, what is the intended file that should handle the request?

... what URLs are you actually requesting? (What rules are your "inheriting"?)

Have you confirmed that .htaccess overrides are enable? What version of Apache are you using? A request of the form /profile/user/ should trigger an external 302 redirect to root, given the rules above. If you are not seeing that then it doesn't look like those rules are doing anything.
